# Specify columns format with redefineable command?

Tags: longtable, columns

The users of my class might want to change the column format of a class-provided table. Convenient would be to do this by redefining a command. At [latex.org](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=21116) I found a solution which works for the `table` environment

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\fooformat}{rl}
\begin{document}
\expandafter\tabular\expandafter{\fooformat}
100 & 200 \\ 30  &  40
\endtabular
\end{document}
```

but I use the `longtable` format from package `ltxtable` to be able to use the `X` specifier for potentially rather long tables.

Is there any chance to achieve something similar?

Comment: Throw away that advice. It's wrong and dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to swap the arguments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newenvironment{varlongtable}[2][c]
 {\expandafter\makevarlongtable\expandafter{#2}{#1}}
 {\endlongtable}

\newcommand{\makevarlongtable}[2]{\longtable[#2]{#1}}

\newcommand{\rl}{rl}
\newcommand{\cc}{cc}

\begin{document}

\begin{varlongtable}{\rl}
ABC & def \\
AAAAAA & bbbbbb
\end{varlongtable}

\begin{varlongtable}[l]{\cc}
ABC & def \\
AAAAAA & bbbbbb
\end{varlongtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The advice you found about

```
\expandafter\tabular\expandafter{\fooformat}
```

is ***not*** to be followed. The internal `\tabular` command performs many assignments that in this way are not protected inside a group.

Answer (score 1):

You could use \newcolumntype to store the formats:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{\fooformat}{rl}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{\fooformat}
100 & 200 \\ 30  &  40
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]